# latex doesn't display numbers in caption with beamerposter

Tags: beamer, beamerposter

i'm making a poster using beamerposter and i'm having a problem with subfigures and caption. The problem is that latex is only showing the caption text, but doesn't show the letters like ((a) caption a)

Here is what i'm doing:

```
\documentclass[final,hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{mytheme}}

\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.4,debug]{beamerposter}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}


\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\captionsetup{labelformat=simple}

\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered tabularx columns

\begin{beamercolorbox}{block title}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ZZ}

            \begin{subfigure}[b]{\linewidth}
                \includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{result-test-22-multiples}
                \caption{asdasd}  
            \end{subfigure}  &

            \begin{subfigure}[b]{\linewidth}
                \includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{result-test-22-single}
                \caption{asdasd}
            \end{subfigure}

            \end{tabularx}
        \end{figure}


\end{beamercolorbox}
```

And here is the theme, sorry it's a bit messy:

```
\ProvidesPackage{mytheme} 

\RequirePackage{tangocolors}
\selectcolormodel{cmyk}
\mode<presentation>

\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=taaluminium,fg=black}

\setbeamercolor{headline}{fg=tabutter,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{footline}{fg=tabutter, bg=blue}
\setbeamerfont{footline}{size=\LARGE,series=\bf}
\setbeamercolor{separation line}{bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{title in headline}{fg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{author in headline}{fg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{institute in headline}{fg=green}

\setbeamercolor{framesubtitle}{fg=ta3orange, bg=ta2gray}
\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{fg=blue, bg=white}
%\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{fg=blue, bg=white}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}


%\setbeamercolor*{normal text}{fg=tachameleon, bg=ta3gray}
\setbeamercolor*{block body}{bg=taaluminium,fg=black}
%\setbeamercolor*{block title}{fg=taorange,bg=ta3skyblue}
\setbeamerfont{block title}{size=\large,series=\bf}
\setbeamercolor{upper separation line head}{fg=ta2orange}

%\setbeamercolor*{example body}{fg=ta3aluminium,bg=white}
%\setbeamercolor*{example text}{fg=ta3aluminium,bg=black}
%\setbeamercolor*{example title}{bg=taorange,fg=ta2gray}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=red}

%\setbeamercolor{example text}{fg=taorange}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=white}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[triangle]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}  % no navigation on a poster
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=ta2skyblue}
\setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg=black}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[circle]


\setbeamertemplate{block begin}{
\vskip.75ex
\begin{beamercolorbox}[rounded=true,shadow=false,leftskip=1cm,colsep*=.75ex]  {block title}%
\usebeamerfont*{block title}\insertblocktitle
\end{beamercolorbox}%
{\ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{}{\nointerlineskip\vskip-0.5pt}}%
\usebeamerfont{block body}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}   [rounded=true,shadow=false,colsep*=.75ex,sep=.75ex,vmode]{block body}%
\ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{\vskip-.25ex}{\vskip-.75ex}\vbox{}%
}
\setbeamertemplate{block end}{
\end{beamercolorbox}
}


\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}
{
   % separates paragraphs in a block
   \setlength{\parskip}{12pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}%
   \begin{adjustwidth}{1cm}{1cm}
}

\addtobeamertemplate{block end}
{\end{adjustwidth}%
\vspace{1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.5ex}}% Pads bottom of block





\setbeamertemplate{headline}{  
\leavevmode

\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{headline}
\begin{columns}[T]
\begin{column}{.02\paperwidth}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.3\paperwidth}
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=.3\paperwidth]{banner}
\end{center}

\end{column}
\begin{column}{.65\paperwidth}
    \vskip3ex
    \raggedleft
    \usebeamercolor{title in headline}{\color{fg}     \textbf{\LARGE{\inserttitle}}\\[1ex]}
    \usebeamercolor{author in headline}{\color{fg}\large{\insertauthor}\\[1ex]}
    \usebeamercolor{institute in headline}{\color{fg}  \large{\insertinstitute}\\[1ex]}     
  \end{column}
  \begin{column}{.03\paperwidth}
  \end{column}
  \end{columns}
 \end{beamercolorbox}

 \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{lower separation line head}
  \rule{0pt}{2pt}
 \end{beamercolorbox}
}

%  \setbeamertemplate{headline}{  
%    \leavevmode
%    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.5cm,wd=.8\paperwidth]{headline}
%      \usebeamercolor{title in headline}{\raggedleft\color{fg}   \textbf{\LARGE{\inserttitle}}\\[1ex]}
%      \usebeamercolor{author in headline}{\raggedleft\color{fg} \large{\insertauthor}\\[1ex]}
%      \usebeamercolor{institute in headline}{\raggedleft\color{fg} \large{\insertinstitute}\\[1ex]}     
%    \end{beamercolorbox}%
%    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.2\paperwidth]{logo in headline}
%      \centering
%      \LARGE{LOGO}
%    \end{beamercolorbox}  


%}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
 \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{upper separation line foot}
  \rule{0pt}{2pt}
 \end{beamercolorbox}

\leavevmode%

 \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2em,leftskip=1cm,rightskip=1cm]{author in  head/foot}%
  \begin{columns}[T]
  \begin{column}{.80\paperwidth} 
  \centering \Large{Institute}
   \hfill
  \vskip1ex
 \end{column}
 \begin{column}{.15\linewidth} 
   \includegraphics[scale=.8]{logo}
   \vskip1ex
 \end{column}    
 \end{columns}
 \end{beamercolorbox}
 \vskip0pt%
 \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{lower separation line foot}
  \rule{0pt}{2pt}

  \end{beamercolorbox}
 }


% Display a grid to help align images ... and it looks nice with this color scheme
%\beamertemplategridbackground[1cm]


\mode<all>



%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex  
%%% TeX-PDF-mode: t
%%% TeX-master: "poster"
%%% End:
```

Comment: Commenting out the line `\usetheme{mytheme}` the numbering is shown as expected (at least on my system). If you commant out that line do you get the numbering? If so, we would need to see the theme used.

Comment: Yes, commenting that line displayed the corrected caption, i will edit my question and put the theme. Thanks

Comment: Got it, it was the color of the caption i added a \setbeamercolor{caption name}{fg=black}, and now it shows. Thanks!

Comment: indeed! I was just writing the answer with an explanation and the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the theme used has

```
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=white}
```

and when building numbered captions, `beamer` uses (see the file `beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty`):

```
\usebeamercolor[fg]{caption name}
```

so the caption number will appear white over a light background and will be almost invisible; to correct this, set the `caption name` color appropriately; for example (change `red` to the desired color):

```
\setbeamercolor{caption name}{fg=red}
```